# What's the difference of JAXP, JDOM, DOM4J,and XERCES?

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jaxp

What is the difference of them?  It is said that JAXP is only a API Specification, JDOM and DOM4J realized it, is it right? And all of them need a XML parser, just like XERCES, is it right?
  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're comparing apples and automobiles.

- JAXP is an API that is now bundled with the JDK
- JDOM is a different API, but also a library
- DOM4J is also a different API and library
- XERCES is a XML parser implemented in Java. A version of XERCES is also bundled in the JDK.

Which API you use is largely a question of personal preference. I like JDOM in part because I'm used to working with it. There are, similarly, several implementations of XML parsers. If you're programming in Java using a recent JDK, you will be able to use JAXP without having to add external libraries.

Comment: To be fair, I also like JDOM because it has a Java, object-oriented design feel to it, unlike other APIs, which tend to be more XML-centric and language-agnostic.

Answer (score 13):

[**JAXP (JSR-206)**](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=206)

Is a set of standard APIs for Java XML parsers.  It covers the following areas:

- DOM (`org.w3c.dom` package)
- SAX (`org.xml.sax` package)
- StAX/JSR-173 (`java.xml.stream`)
- XSLT (`javax.xml.transform`)
- XPath (`javax.xml.xpath`)
- Validation (`javax.xml.validation`)
- Datatypes (`javax.xml.datatype`)

This standard was created by an expert group with representatives from many companies and individuals.  As a standard this means there are multiple implementations (Xerces implements JAXP), and it can be included in the JDK.

**Xerces**

Is an open source Java XML parser that provides DOM and  SAX implementations that are compliant with the JAXP standard.

**JDOM and DOM4J**

Are open source Java XML parsers.

Comment: so, JDOM and DOM4J only supprt DOM? That is the difference of JDOM&DOM4J and XERCES?

Comment: JDOM and DOM4J support an object representation of XML.  I do not believe that they support the W3C concept of a DOM:  http://www.w3.org/DOM